# Reliable disk image format

Tags: virtual-machine

I've recently ran into disk image corruption issues if the host computer crashes. I'm experimenting with different hardware setups and a host PC crash caused (already a few times) the VHD image to be corrupted. This happened both in VMWare or VirtualBox.

The host machine is Win 10 and so is the hosted image, 100-150GB in size. The image is of an SSD residing on a HDD.

Short of doing a full backup (which is slow) what other options do I have? I could dedicate a partition on the host computer which would likely improve the chances of recovery. I've switched to a VMDK format but not sure if that changes anything. Differential backup/snapshot would be nice but I don't know how to set that up.
Trying to get away with free software as it's home use.

Comment: When you say the image is of an SSD, what do you actually mean? Personally, I'd would work to diagnose and resolve the crashing issues. Especially in home setups it is unlikely you'll find a disk image format that is immune to corruption when crashes happen.

Comment: Im a Linux KVM user hence a comment only - I posit your problem is write caching on the VM host for data on the VM.  This can be disabled - See section 6.7 of https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html. (I disagree with @music2myear assertion about disk formats that are immune to corruption in home environments, btw)

Comment: Overclocking, trying to get the highest single-core performance for my tasks. Still testing though, that's why I need to make sure everything is reliable. I don't mind a crash once-in-a-while as long as it doesn't take everything with it. I could try to disable caching but everything else will be slowed down to a crawl, since it's an HDD. The image is from a small SSD and did not find a way to make vmware/windows change it to an HDD.